# How to increase the char column width for the scalacheck console output?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalacheck

When running `scalacheck` from an `sbt console` the output is limited by 76 char column width:

```
$ sbt test:console

import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scalacheck.ScalazProperties._
import scalacheck.ScalazArbitrary._
import scalacheck.ScalaCheckBinding._

scala> monad.laws[List].check
+ monad.applicative.apply.functor.invariantFunctor.identity: OK, passed 100
   tests.
+ monad.applicative.apply.functor.invariantFunctor.composite: OK, passed 10
  0 tests.
+ monad.applicative.apply.functor.identity: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.applicative.apply.functor.composite: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.applicative.apply.composition: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.applicative.identity: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.applicative.homomorphism: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.applicative.interchange: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.applicative.map consistent with ap: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.bind.apply.functor.invariantFunctor.identity: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.bind.apply.functor.invariantFunctor.composite: OK, passed 100 tests
  .
+ monad.bind.apply.functor.identity: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.bind.apply.functor.composite: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.bind.apply.composition: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.bind.associativity: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.bind.ap consistent with bind: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.right identity: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ monad.left identity: OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Is there any way to increase that limit?

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not possible to change, as it is hard-coded in ScalaCheck (in https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/util/ConsoleReporter.scala). I suggest opening an issue at ScalaCheck's Github page.

Comment: Did you find where in the scalacheck code this has been hard-coded?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible as the width value is hard coded in `ConsoleReporter`.  However, if you are running your tests with the `main` defined in `Properties`, you can do the following:

```
object MyCheck extends Properties("My property check") {

  override def overrideParameters(p: Test.Parameters) =
      p.withTestCallback(WideConsoleReporter)

  ...

}
```

And then in your own code, create `WideConsoleReporter` based on `ConsoleReporter`.